# How can I get the angle of the order parameter

Tags: mean-field-theory

I read a paper(PRL 100, 156401 (2008)), I want to try to draw picture 2 by myself. But I don't konw how to get the $\bar\phi$ and $\phi$.The honeycomb lattice is bipartite, consisting of two triangular sublattices (referred to here as A and B).They are defined as follows：
$\chi_{i,i+b_s} = \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\chi & = & |\chi|e^{i\phi_A} \\ 
y & = & |\chi|e^{i\phi_B} 
\end{aligned}
\right.$
According to the mean field,the following selfconsistent equations can get:\begin{aligned}
& \rho=\frac{1}{6 L^2} \sum_k \frac{V_1 \rho+2 V_2 \chi S_{\boldsymbol{k}+\bar{\phi}} S_\phi}{\sqrt{|t(\boldsymbol{k})|^2+\left(V_1 \rho+2 V_2 \chi S_{\boldsymbol{k}+\bar{\phi}} S_\phi\right)^2}} \\
& \chi=\frac{S_\phi}{6 L^2} \sum_k \frac{S_{\boldsymbol{k}+\bar{\phi}}\left(V_1 \rho+2 V_2 \chi S_{k+\bar{\phi}} S_\phi\right)}{\sqrt{|t(\boldsymbol{k})|^2+\left(V_1 \rho+2 V_2 \chi S_{k+\bar{\phi}} S_\phi\right)^2}}
\end{aligned}
In these, $S_{\phi} = sin(\phi)$ and $S_{k+\bar\phi} = \sum{sin(k\cdot b_n+\bar\phi)}$.How do I represent them in the program